EntityFramework 7, populate a property from another table
I have a TasksDbContext for my Tasks table where each task has a user identified by a UserId field, but the Users table is in a different database and is managed by a different team's UsersDbContext. Is there a way to populate the task's UserName property in my DbContext without stepping on the other team's toes with regards to datamigrations etc.?
I would prefer to avoid looping through the tasks and getting the user name for each individual item by using the other team's UsersDbContext.
public class TasksDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; } = default!

    public TasksDbContext (DbContextOptions<TasksDbContext > options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}

public class Task
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string UserName { get; set; } // Stored in the other Users table.
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
}


Which database are you using? In SQL Server cross-database queries are possible, as long as the databases are in the same SQL Server instance. It's not even considered a distributed query. You can easily create a VIEW in your database that returns the other database's table and map to it. If the view returns the same columns as the User task you may be able to use the existing class in your context

When you use View mapping no migrations are generated for the view

Assuming both of the databases are on the same SQL Server instance, just create a stored procedure and call it using EF. In the stored procedure, don't forget to mention the database name in the join query (e.g., like DbName.dbo.Tasks)

@CSharp why a stored procedure? A stored procedure's results can't be combined in another query

He just needs the result in C#. He didn't mention another query. Once he gets the result in C# List, he can further use it for query.
Something like this is fine:
T.UserId,
U.Username,
U.Text,
U.Done
from TasksDatabse.dbo.Tasks T
left outer join UsersDatabase.dbo.Users U
on T.UserId = U.Id```

Thanks for the comments, guys! I guess what I was hoping for was a way to annotate the UserName property, or apply some modelBuilder instruction for it, that would in turn apply a JOIN behind the scenes. An SP is of course possible, I was just curious if this was within the capabilities of an EF DbContext without having the developer write SQL...

Create a stored proc and call it in dapper/EF and get the result as IEnumerable. SQL query will be something like:
select T.Id as TaskId,
T.UserId,
U.Username,
U.Text,
U.Done
from TasksDatabse.dbo.Tasks T
left outer join UsersDatabase.dbo.Users U
on T.UserId = U.Id


What you want to achieve is possible using a feature EF Core calls "entity splitting".
Code would look like this:
modelBuilder.Entity<Task>(
    entityBuilder =>
    {
        entityBuilder
            .ToTable("Tasks")
            .SplitToTable(
                "Users",
                tableBuilder =>
                {
                    tableBuilder.Property(task => task.UserName).HasColumnName("Name");
                });
    });

I believe the biggest challenge you are going to have however is the fact that the 2 tables are in different databases (and consequently don't have a constraint between them). I think that will force you to have to create a view in the database where Task is that surfaces the User table from the other database, and then map that view as if it was a table.
However, having said that, I believe you'd be better off reconsidering your design. Instead of attempting to map that legacy table alongside your "new" tables, you could tap into the legacy system to notify you of user changes and then map a version of the "users" table on your new database. This would completely decouple your new components from the legacy ones.

As you mentioned Tasks and Users are in separate databases, there are various ways to handle this but other team might need to some part of the work as well to help you out:

Ask Team Users to create a synonym of their Users Database, and you can query that Users table via ORM or Stored Procedures using that synonym.
Ask Team Users to create a function which takes input userId and returns UserName, which you can again use via ORM or stored Procedure.
Team Users can create an API or a message broker which takes input userId, and provides userName.

If you are expecting to access USERS table in your own dbcontext, thats not do-able.

This is almost certainly a ChatGPT answer or copy pasta. One option is completely unrelated, one could help and one would cause performance issues and require too much work. While the easier option is missing

Down-voting an answer is easier, this is something we used to do depending upon the requirements from the user. this is from experience not an AI tool
@PanagiotisKanavos

Answers are downvoted if they're bad. What does an API or worse, message broker have to do with the question? Come to think of it, what do you mean by synonym of their Users database? In what database product? If you meant table synonym in SQL Server this could be useful. The last line contradicts the entire answer too: that's not do-able. You posted 1.5 possible options

As the contexts are different and there is a possibility that Teams Users database wont be accessible, so one can create an API at Team Users end which can be called, to fetch UserName, and if both teams are working in a single project, than there can be a message broker which can be called to fetch userName.

@PanagiotisKanavos
Table Synonym in SQL thats what i meant, and similarly function here means Database function.
